# Traefik configuration always returning 404

Tags: http, traefik

I must be doing something simple wrong, but... why is every request to this Traefik server returning a 404?

Here's traefik.yaml:

```yaml
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"

  websecure:
    address: ":443"

  traefik:
    address: ":9000"

providers:
  file:
    filename: traefik-routes.yaml

accessLog: {}

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true
```

And traefik-routes.yaml — I'm trying to set a catch-all route with `PathPrefix(`/`)`:

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    mistserver:
      service: mistserver
      rule: PathPrefix(`/`) 
      priority: 100

  services:
    mistserver:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: http://localhost:8080/

tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: tls.crt
      keyFile: tls.key
```

The access log shows the request as not matching any routers. Why?

```
[root@krabbucket traefik]# ./traefik --log.level=d
INFO[0000] Configuration loaded from file: /root/traefik/traefik.yaml
192.168.137.119 - - [09/Mar/2022:11:16:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 2 "-" "-" 0ms
192.168.137.119 - - [09/Mar/2022:11:16:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 3 "-" "-" 0ms
192.168.137.119 - - [09/Mar/2022:11:16:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 4 "-" "-" 0ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Traefik requires separate routes for TLS and non-TLS in this context. This revised `traefik-routes.yaml` worked prefecty:

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    mistserver:
      service: mistserver
      rule: PathPrefix(`/`)
      priority: 100

    mistserver-tls:
      service: mistserver
      rule: PathPrefix(`/`)
      priority: 100
      tls: {}

  services:
    mistserver:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: http://localhost:8080/

tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: tls.crt
      keyFile: tls.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service URL is defined as `http://localhost:8080/` when traefik tries to route you to the service it resolves to traefik itself.

Are you trying to reach the dashboard? If so the set the service to `api@internal`

```
http:
  routers:
    mistserver:
      service: api@interna
      rule: PathPrefix(`/`)
      priority: 100
```

Then you can reach the dashboard via `http://your-ip/dashboard/#/`

Otherwise your router and service name `mistserver` looks like you are trying to reach something on the machine itself.
If so you can't use localhost to reach your machine because that will resolve to traefik itself.

But rather you can use your public ip address instead of localhost or run traefik in [host mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/).

Comment: The external service that I was trying to proxy to was indeed running on port 8080. Traefik itself was running on ports 80, 443, and 9000.